# MATLAB's lsqnonlin solver moves away from solution

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization, solver

I have a fitting problem that I am trying to solve using MATLAB's `lsqnonlin` function and it's doing a pretty poor job. In particular, if I give it the actual solution as the starting point, the solver proceeds to move away from there (despite the fitting function returning a vector of all zeroes for that input) and produces something awful. My code is below, but it's a bit long, so I apologise for that, but I'm not sure exactly what it is about this particular situation that causes this behaviour as in others it's fine.

fitting_demo.m:

```
% Parameters for image
imagemat = zeros(32, 32);
x_centre = 5; y_centre = -10; radius = 3; psf_sigma = 1; height = 1;

% Generate image to fit
actual_image = image_sphere_thin(x_centre, y_centre, radius, psf_sigma, height, imagemat);

figure

% Plot actual image
subplot(2, 1, 1)
imagesc(actual_image)
axis equal
title('Actual image')

% Set up fitting function
x0 = [x_centre, y_centre, radius, psf_sigma, height]; % The solver starts from the solution!
f = @(x)fit_image_sphere_thin(x, imagemat);

% Fit
options = optimoptions(@lsqnonlin, 'Display', 'iter');
[fit, resnorm, residual, exitflag, output] = lsqnonlin(f, x0, [], [], options);

% Display image generated using fitted parameters
subplot(2, 1, 2)
imagesc(image_sphere_thin(fit(1), fit(2), fit(3), fit(4), fit(5), imagemat))
axis equal
title('Fitted image')
```

fit_image_sphere_thin.m:

```
function deltas = fit_image_sphere_thin(x0, actual_image)

x_centre       = x0(1);
y_centre       = x0(2);
radius         = x0(3);
% psf_sigma      = x0(4); % Commented out to stop crazy things
psf_sigma = 1;
% height         = x0(5); % Commented out to stop crazy things
height = 1;

imagemat = zeros(size(actual_image));

sim_image = image_sphere_thin(x_centre, y_centre, radius, psf_sigma, height, imagemat);

sim_vector = sim_image(:);
actual_vector = actual_image(:);

deltas = actual_vector - sim_vector;

end
```

image_sphere_thin.m:

```
function I = image_sphere_thin(x_centre, y_centre, radius, psf_sigma, height, imagemat)

image_width = size(imagemat, 2);
image_height = size(imagemat, 1);

image_centre_x = image_width / 2;
image_centre_y = image_height / 2;

x = (1:image_width) - image_centre_x;
y = -(1:image_height) + image_centre_y;

[x, y] = meshgrid(x, y);
X = [x(:) y(:)];

image_vector = cross_section_sphere_thin(x_centre, y_centre, radius, psf_sigma, height, X);

imagemat = reshape(image_vector, size(imagemat));
I = imagemat;

end
```

cross_section_sphere_thin.m:

```
function I = cross_section_sphere_thin(x_centre, y_centre, radius, psf_sigma, height, X)

r = sqrt((X(:, 1) - x_centre).^2 + (X(:, 2) - y_centre).^2);
psf_variance = psf_sigma^2;
I = height * (exp(-(r - radius).^2 / (2 * psf_sigma)) - exp(-(r + radius).^2 / (2 * psf_sigma))) ./ r;
I(r == 0) = (2 * radius * height / psf_variance) * exp(-(radius^2) / (2 * psf_variance));

end
```

Comment: Hi,  please remember to post the version of `matlab` and the toolbox, if any, that your called functions belong to.  In the meantime, try generating your image file and extracting whatever slice you intend to feed to `lsqnonlin` and see what happens.  As it stands you've run your data through so many functions and contortions that there's no easy way to verify you've sent valid data to the fitting function.